# update pyspark data frame column based on another column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Below is a data frame in `pyspark`. I want to update the column `val` in `data frame` based on the values in `tests` column.

```
df.show()
+---------+----+---+
|    tests| val|asd|
+---------+----+---+
|    test1|   Y|  1|
|    test2|   N|  2|
|    test2|   Y|  1|
|    test1|   N|  2|
|    test1|   N|  3|
|    test3|   N|  4|
|    test4|   Y|  5|
+---------+----+---+
```

I want to update the value when the any given `test` has `val` `Y` then all `val's` of that particular tests should be updated to `Y`. if not then what ever values they have.

basically I want the `data frame` to be like below.

```
result_df.show()

+---------+----+---+
|    tests| val|asd|
+---------+----+---+
|    test1|   Y|  1|
|    test2|   Y|  2|
|    test2|   Y|  1|
|    test1|   Y|  2|
|    test1|   Y|  3|
|    test3|   N|  4|
|    test4|   Y|  5|
+---------+----+---+
```

What should I do to achieve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `max` window function and `selectExpr`:

```python
df.selectExpr(
    'tests', 'max(val) over (partition by tests) as val', 'asd'
).show()

+-----+---+---+
|tests|val|asd|
+-----+---+---+
|test4|  Y|  5|
|test3|  N|  4|
|test1|  Y|  1|
|test1|  Y|  2|
|test1|  Y|  3|
|test2|  Y|  2|
|test2|  Y|  1|
+-----+---+---+
```

Comment: I am getting the following error `Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 876, in selectExpr
    jdf = self._jdf.selectExpr(self._jseq(expr)  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o177.selectExpr.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.15] failure: end of input expected

max(val) over (partition by tests) as val
              ^
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
`

Comment: I imported `Window` function from `pyspark.sql` as well

Comment: Moreover I am using `spark 1.6`

Comment: @user9367133 this should work for you. Equivalently you can `import pyspark.sql.functions as f` and do `df.select('tests', f.max('val').over(Window.partitionBy('tests')).alias('val'), 'asd').show()`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution.
First we find out for each test whether it has val Y.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf
by_test = df.groupBy('tests').agg(sf.sum((sf.col('val') == 'Y').cast('int')).alias('HasY'))
by_test.show()
+-----+----+
|tests|HasY|
+-----+----+
|test4|   1|
|test3|   0|
|test1|   1|
|test2|   1|
+-----+----+
```

Join back to the origine dataframe

```python
df = df.join(by_test, on='tests')
df.show()
+-----+---+---+----+
|tests|val|asd|HasY|
+-----+---+---+----+
|test4|  Y|  5|   1|
|test3|  N|  4|   0|
|test1|  Y|  1|   1|
|test1|  N|  2|   1|
|test1|  N|  3|   1|
|test2|  N|  2|   1|
|test2|  Y|  1|   1|
+-----+---+---+----+
```

Create a new column with the same name using when/otherwise

```python
df = df.withColumn('val', sf.when(sf.col('HasY') > 0, 'Y').otherwise(sf.col('val')))
df = df.drop('HasY')
df.show()
+-----+---+---+
|tests|val|asd|
+-----+---+---+
|test4|  Y|  5|
|test3|  N|  4|
|test1|  Y|  1|
|test1|  Y|  2|
|test1|  Y|  3|
|test2|  Y|  2|
|test2|  Y|  1|
+-----+---+---+
```